# Search and Append

Tags: bash, search, awk, append

I have been looking for a way to solve my problem, but have come to give up. I am pretty new to scripting so please bear with me. This is what I am trying to do:

I have a file (let's call it file1) with 6 columns. On the first column there is an ID, and on the 7th there is an Alternate ID, but that whole column is empty:

```
ID col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 AltID AltID2
a   a    x    43   5    54   A1     D3
b   f    4    44   9    51   B3     KL5
c   h    k    90   0    52   K9     JD3
...
```

I have another set of files (6 to be precise) that each have 8 columns (they are tab delimited files). The 4th column contains IDs that match the ones from File1, col=ID, but in a random order.

What I need to do is search for every ID in each row of the 1st column from File1 in the 4th column of the 6 other files I have, and when there is a match, put that match on the 7th column of File1.

Another tricky thing is that some of these IDs are entirely missing (in which case they need to have an "x"), and other times they have more than one Alternate ID (in which case, I place them next to each other, in columns 7 and 8 of File1)

I tried grep for a bit, but then stumbled upon people saying awk is actually better for this. I tried building a script and came up with this:

```
#! /bin/bash

while read fn; do

STR =$(echo -ne "${fn}" ; awk '  { if($4=="${fn}") printf "%s\t", $7} ' ./*.txt)
echo $STR > test.txt

done < dreg.txt
```

It obviously didn't work, and I know the code looks like I wasn't sure about what I was doing (I wasn't), but it's where I started. I was essentially trying to read a dummy file I created with only the first column with text, and then searching for every line on all the other text files in that directory. Then, if found, I was echoing the name of the ID, followed by the alternate IDs, hoping to get the following format:

ID AltID AltID2

My plan was to print these results into a file and then go from there, but it didn't work. It is not the most elegant solution, but like I said, I am not very proficient at this.

Any help you guys have will be greatly appreciated. If you need another example or for me to clarify things, please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that

- there is no ID with more than 2 alternatives
- the alternative IDs are in the first columns of the "other" files
- you only want the "x" to appear in col7 when there is no match, not in col8 if there is only one match
- you can name one character (`DELIM`) that is no `<TAB>` and will **never** appear in any *altenative* ID
- all files have *exactly* **one** header line

the following solution works for me

```sh
$ cat file1
```

```
ID      col2    col3    col4    col5    col6
a       a       x       43      5       54
b       f       4       44      9       51
c       h       k       90      0       52
```

```sh
$ cat file2a
```

```
AltID   col2    col3    ID
A1      some    thing   a
B1      more    stuff   b
```

```sh
$ cat file2b
```

```
AltID   col2    col3    ID
A2      even    more    a
D1      random  stuff   d
```

```sh
$ cat test.awk
```

```sh
BEGIN {
   FS = "\t"
   OFS = FS
   DELIM = ";"
   MISSING = "x"
}
FILENAME != "file1" {
   if (FNR != 1) {
      alt[$4] = (alt[$4] ? alt[$4] "" DELIM : "") "" $1
   }
   next
}
FNR == 1 {
   $7 = "AltID"
   $8 = "AltID2"
   print
   next
}
{
   idcount = split(alt[$1], ids, DELIM)
   $7 = (idcount ? ids[1] : MISSING)
}
idcount > 1 {
    $8 = ids[2]
}
1
```

```sh
$ awk -f test.awk file2* file1
```

```
ID      col2    col3    col4    col5    col6    AltID   AltID2
a       a       x       43      5       54      A1      A2
b       f       4       44      9       51      B1
c       h       k       90      0       52      x
```

Feel free to ask for adjustements or explanations in comments and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi sg-lecram
Thanks a lot for the script. It works almost flawlessly. I'm having an issue right now where it will put "x" on the second column occasionally and the ID on the first. I also noticed that at some points it prints the ID twice, so I end up with three columns at certain points.

Comment: Actually, ignore that. I figured out the problem. I had line breaks inserted by excel into the txt file. Got rid of them and it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!